# Need to restrict user to write in space between table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new in programming.
I want to restrict user to write something between space of table:

[image]

Comment: Use input tags inside the table, what did you try?

Comment: Could you provide the HTML and possibly CSS or JS code for that table?

Comment: YEs I have Added Html,css,Js

Comment: <div id ="editable_area" style="background-color:Violet;width:50%; height :200px;" contenteditable="true" >div parent
    <table style="background-color:rgb(38, 164, 184);">
    <tr><td></td></tr></table>
    </div>

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        var parentOfTable = $("table").parent().css({"color": "yellow","border": "5px solid yellow","pointer-events":"text"});
        var childOfDiv = $("div").children().css({"color": "white", "border": "5px solid blue","pointer-events":"text"});
      
    });

Answer (score 0):

use "contenteditable" attribute inside your table column tags like that:

```
<div id="editable_area" contenteditable> Hey bro, you can edit me tho =D</div>
```

With these attribute, user can edit inside the div and you can get the value of it using scripts. I mean, smth like that:

```
let valueOfTableCell = document.querySelector("#editable_area").innerText;
```